# Laravel formatting currency from DB field

Tags: laravel, formatting, decimal, currency

I have a field in my DB called 'value' that is of type decimal (9,2).

I am coding in Laravel 4 and I am trying to use accessors and mutators to format the content of this to include a comma for thousands and also to set format a value with a comma back to a decimal so it will save to the DB without throwing an error.

Example:
DB value: 1234.00
Display value: 1,234.00

I think I've sorted out the formatting when reading from the DB using the following code in the model

```
public function getValueAttribute($value)
{

  if ($value !== NULL)
  {
    return number_format($value, 2);
  }

}
```

The issue I seem to have is setting the format correctly when it saves.

```
public function setValueAttribute($value)
{

  $this->attributes['value'] = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $value)));

}
```

This results in values over 1000 having the comma removed and the decimal point put in it's place

Example:
Display value: 1,234.00
DB value: 1.23

Any ideas how I take a value with commas in (UK currency) and store it as a decimal in the DB correctly????

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick:

```
public function setValueAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['value'] = floatval(preg_replace('/[^\d.]/', '', $value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is still useful to someone, please have a look at [PHP money_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function setValueAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['value'] = preg_replace('/([0-9]{2})$/', ".$1", preg_replace('/[\D]+/','', $value));
}
```